# curve fitting with a numerical model in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math

I have some data points to fit with a model. My model is not defined as an equation but as a numerical solution of 3 equations.
My model is defined as below:

```
def eq(q):
    z1=q[0]
    z2=q[1]
    H=q[2]

    F=empty((3))
    F[0] = ((J*(1-(D*(1-(1-8*a*T/D**3)**(1/3)))**(b)/Lx))*sin(z1-z2))+(H*sin(z1-pi/4))+(((3.6*10**5)/2)*sin(2*z1))
    F[1] = ((-J*(1-(D*(1-(1-8*a*T/D**3)**(1/3)))**(b)/Lx))*sin(z1-z2))+(H*sin(z2-pi/4))+(((3.6*10**5)/2)*sin(2*z2))
    F[2] = cos(z1-pi/4)
    return F

guess1=array([2.35,0.2,125000])
z=fsolve(eq,guess1)
Hc=z[2]*(1-(T/Tb)**(1/2))
```

that

```
D=10**(-8)
a=2.2*10**(-28)
Lx=4.28*10**(-9)
```

and `J`, `b`, `Tb` are parameters and `z1`, `z2`, `H` are variables

My data points are:

```
T=[10, 60, 110, 160, 210, 260, 300]

Hc=[0.58933, 0.5783, 0.57938, 0.58884, 0.60588, 0.62788, 0.6474]
```

how can I find `J`, `b`, `Tb` according to fitting model with data points?

Comment: I don't understand what your data is. What are the values of ```J```, ```b``` and ```Tb```? What are the elements in vector ```F``` output in function ```eq```?

Comment: I have a model that consists of 3 equations: F[0], F[1] and F[2] that variables are z1, z2 and H. These 3 equations should be solved numerically by fsolve as a set of equations. after that, we put the third component of fsolve (z[2]) into Hc=z[2]*(1-(T/Tb)**(1/2)). in this model D, a, Lx are constants. Now I want to use T and Hc data points in order to fit this model and after that find J, b, Tb parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. You need to understand that curve_fit will only care about the input and the output of your function, such that you need to define it this way :

```
def func(x, *params):
    ....
    return y
```

Then you can apply `curve_fit` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html):

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y_data)
```

I wrote and example taking your case. There is 100 ways to write it more efficiently. However, I tried to make it clear so you can understand the link between what you gave and what I propose.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve, curve_fit

def eq(q, T, J, b): 

    z1 = q[0]
    z2 = q[1]
    H = q[2]

    D=10**(-8)
    a=2.2*10**(-28)
    Lx=4.28*10**(-9)    


    F = np.empty((3))
    F[0] = ((J*(1-(D*(1-(1-8*a*T/D**3)**(1/3)))**(b)/Lx))*np.sin(z1-z2))+(H*np.sin(z1-np.pi/4))+(((3.6*10**5)/2)*np.sin(2*z1))
    F[1] = ((-J*(1-(D*(1-(1-8*a*T/D**3)**(1/3)))**(b)/Lx))*np.sin(z1-z2))+(H*np.sin(z2-np.pi/4))+(((3.6*10**5)/2)*np.sin(2*z2))
    F[2] = np.cos(z1-np.pi/4)
    return F

def func(T,J,b,Tb):
    Hc = []
    guess1 = np.array([2.35,0.2,125000])
    for t in T :
        z = fsolve(eq, guess1, args = (t, J, b))
        Hc.append(z[2]*(1-(t/Tb)**(1/2)))
    return Hc

T = [10, 60, 110, 160, 210, 260, 300]
Hc_exp = [0.58933, 0.5783, 0.57938, 0.58884, 0.60588, 0.62788, 0.6474]

p0 = (1,1,100)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, T, Hc_exp, p0)

J = popt[0]
b = popt[1]
Tb = popt[2]
```

It seems that the fit is hard to be done. To improve that, you can add an initial guess to the parameters through `p0`, or adding bounds to the parameters (see `curve_fit` documentation). Once it converges, you can have the error on the estimated parameters.