# 'Not a proper array of floats' error using numerical model in scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a numerical model to data using sp.optimize.curve_fit to find my free parameters, but I am getting the error "Result from function call is not a proper array of floats." (it is somewhere within sp.optimize.curve_fit). So far I have

```
def N2_fit(t,N2initial,C_up):
    initValues = np.array([Nconc-N2initial,N2initial,0,0,0,0])
    C = C_up
    t_span = [t[0],t[len(t)-1]]
    solution = solve_ivp(dN_dt,t_span,initValues,dense_output = True)
    z = solution.sol(t)
    N2_plot = z[1,:]
    N2_fit = np.array([t,N2_plot])
    return N2_fit

popt, pcov = sp.optimize.curve_fit(N2_fit,time,N2_data)
```

I am also calling the function dN_dt from earlier

```
def dN_dt(t,N):
    N1 = N[0]
    N2 = N[1]
    N3 = N[2]
    dN1dt = N2*W21 + N3*W31 + ((N2)**2)*C
    dN2dt = -N2*W21 + N3*W32 - 2*((N2)**2)*C
    dN3dt = ((N2)**2)*C - N3*(W32 + W31)
    dN = [dN1dt, dN2dt, dN3dt,N1,N2,N3]
    return dN
```

(all the W** values are just constants, I've defined those earlier)

I've been looking at these two questions, but I'm still not really getting past this error:

[scipy curve_fit error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184541/scipy-curve-fit-error-result-from-function-call-is-not-a-proper-array-of-floats)
and 
[curve fitting with a numerical model in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51440058/curve-fitting-with-a-numerical-model-in-python)

(also, for full disclosure this is for a uni assignment)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome. As a general hint try to give a complete and minimal "working" example. This means provide code that could run stand alone including all imports. That said, a second tip: try not to name variables like your functions (have, e.g. a look at PEP8 for naming convention that make your life easier). Finally, I think that `N2_fit` (the funcion) should return a one-dimensional array, i.e. without the list `t`. I think it should be `z` as the `__call__()` to `OdeSolution` already provides a 1D array.

Comment: Thank you @mikuszefski . I'll fix up the name of my function. Returning z doesn't work, that leads to the same error, and in any case isn't z a 2D array? As it contains solutions to N1 and N3 as well? If I just return the part containing the solution for N2 (N2_plot above) then I get the error 'Improper input: N=2 must not exceed M=1', so that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Well, the last error happens if the number of values returned is less than the number of parameters to fit. As there is no complete minimal working example, it is impossible to check, but you should have a look at what `N2_fit()` actually returns.